# Android SearchView: Filterable Listview Runtime Error

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, searchview, android-filter

I'm running into an occasional issue when using a filterable listview. Infrequently, I'll get a runtime error when deleting text from my searchview while filtering a listview of recipes. It tends to happen when text is deleted quickly using the soft keyboard.

90% of the time, this implementation works exactly as I'd expect, but when deleting characters rapidly I get the following error.

```
04-07 11:38:55.221    9591-9591/brd.cms.sup E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
04-07 11:38:55.221    9591-9591/brd.cms.sup E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> brd.cms.sup [ userId:0 | appId:10359 ]
04-07 11:38:59.295    9591-9591/brd.cms.sup E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION
04-07 11:40:58.018    9591-9591/brd.cms.sup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: brd.cms.sup , PID: 9591
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131493035, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class brd.cms.sup.RecipeAdapter)]
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1566)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2598)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15860)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4902)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2092)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1267)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6640)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is my SearchView.OnQueryTextListener implementation.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (recipeAdapter != null) {
        try {
            recipeAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is my private RecipeFilter in the RecipeAdapter.

```
private class RecipeFilter extends Filter{
    List<Recipe> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint){
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            filteredList.clear();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                for (Recipe r : backupList) {
                    if (r.contains(constraint)) {
                        filteredList.add(r);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                filteredList.addAll(backupList);
            }
            result.count = filteredList.size();
            result.values = filteredList;
            return result;
        }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        recipeList = (List) results.values;
        if (results != null) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else{
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing how you use `filteredList` and `recipeList` would help.  However your `ListView` getting out of sync is probably revolved around the lack of synchronizations. The `performFiltering()` method executes on the background thread. It's imperative that you synchronize any mutations on those `Lists`...and not just within the `performFiltering()` method but throughout the entire adapter. Which btw, I sure hope your custom adapter is not an extension of the `ArrayAdapter`.  Which would be another problem in itself.

Here's a [short blog post](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/filtering-problems-arrayadapter/) talking about the problems with filtering with Android's `ArrayAdapter`.  At the end of it, you'll find example code showing a good way to write a `Filter` class for an adapter.  Basically the equivalent code you posted here.

**Managing Lists**

To recap, you have a `recipeList` which holds either all the items in the adapter or just the filtered items.  You also have a `backupList` which stores all the items. Then within the `Filter` class, you have a `filterList` which is used to facilitate the filtered data into `recipeList`.

This approach is fairly standard...whereby two main lists are used to track both filtered and original data. The key in working with these lists is synchronization and knowing which one to use.

For any getter, your adapter should always work with data from `recipeList`.  Eg, `getItem()`, `getItemId()`, etc. Accessing this data does not need to be synchronized.

For any setter, you'll do the following

1. Synchronize
2. Determine which list gets updated
3. Call `notifyDataSetChanged`

In regards to #2, based on your setup, no matter what your `backupList` should be updated. Whether or not your `recipeList` also gets updated depends on whether you want mutations to apply during a filtering or not.

Finally, your filter class needs to add synchronizations. Specifically when you are copying data over from the `backupList` to `filteredList`.  Additionally, `filteredList` needs to be local to the method `performFiltering()` and not global to the class.  Either that or synchronize the entire method. Since that method occurs on a background thread, it's very possible for multiple threads to execute that method in tandem. Which would mean they are all changing the same `filteredList`...which is not good.

Also in `publishResults` you'll need to synchronize updating `recipeList` and you need to invoke `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` when results is either null or empty.

Comment: I am extending BaseAdapter for this implementation. The adapter starts using recipeList, and then, when filtered, uses filteredList to shrink the result set, and copies filteredList over recipeList and notify that the data set changed. When the search constraint is blank, I copy the original list (saved as a backupList in the constructor) back over recipe list notify the set changed again. If this is way off let me know, this is all relatively new to me. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed all of your advice, synchronizing the methods seems to have been the most significant alone, but it's running great now. Thanks again!